# Number of elements in the symmetric group with a particular transposition decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

Consider the symmetric group on $n$ symbols, $S_n$. Then, is there a way/ function to count the number of elements with a given number of transposition decomposition?

By transposition decomposition, I mean writing a permutation as a product of transpositions. So, for example, all transpositions have only one transposition factor, all $3$ cycles have exactly two transposition factors. But, the product of two disjoint transpositions also have a decomposition into two transposition factors. I think that counting the number of different cycle decompositions will help a lot. But has this been studied before and is there a function for eveluating it? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question and I believe is an open problem in general.  The literature on Cayley graphs of symmetric groups generated by transpositions would be relevant.   The quantity you are interested in - the number of permutations that are a product of exactly $k$ (and no fewer) transpositions - is the number of vertices in the complete transposition graph whose distance to the identity vertex is exactly $k$.

More specifically, let $S$ be the set of all transpositions in $S_n$ ($n \ge 3)$. The complete transposition graph is the Cayley graph $G = Cay(S_n,S)$, which is defined to be the graph with vertex set $S_n$ and with edge set $\{(h, sh): h \in S_n, s \in S \}$.  Define $G_i(v)$ to be the set of vertices in $G$ whose distance to vertex $v$ is exactly $i$.  Let $e$ denote the identity permutation in $S_n$. Then $G_0(e) = \{e\}$, $G_1(e)$ is the set $S$ of all ${n \choose 2}$ transpositions in $S_n$, and $G_2(e)$ is the set of all permutations in $S_n$ which are either 3-cycles or a product of two disjoint transpositions.

The open source software SAGE (sagemath.org) contains, among other things, built-in functions to create Cayley graphs and output the size of the $i$th layer $G_i(v)$ in the distance partition of $G$ with respect to a vertex $v$.

Comment: actually, i got the question while studying the cayley graph on $S_n$ generated by transpositions, in an attempt tn color (total coloring) the graph is easily seen to be bipartite.

Comment: Yes, with the bipartition being the even and odd permutations.